# Showing forex rates with Shield UI Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shieldui

I want to use Shield UI Chart to access and visualize forex data. I have figured out how to do the ajax stuff:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.apirates.com/jsonp/update',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function (data) {
 }
)
```

However I can’t figure out how to extract the desired currency rates from the data retrieved.

Comment: WHat's the structure for data in response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The available rates are returned as key indexed array. They can be retrieved in a way similar to this:

```
data.ticks.EURUSD,
```

and contain one values, returned by each ajax call. You can further assign as many of the exchange rates to arrays, and than pass them to the chart. You need to declare the arrays:

```
var EURUSD = new Array();
and than pass it to the chart: 
     dataSeries: [
                 {
                 seriesType: 'line',
                 collectionAlias: 'EUR/USD',
                 data: EURUSD,
                 }
    ]
```